# Аналог eval в Excel

Tags: excel

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли аналог функции *eval* в *Excel*. 
В *PHP* эта функция исполняет код, записанный в строке.

У меня в ячейке стоит текст "1+1". Можно ли заставить Excel выполнить этот текст? Нужно получить результат сложения: 2.

Comment: Добавить = перед 1+1?

Comment: Если записать ="="&A1, то получится: =1+1, а нужно число 2

Answer (score 2):

Таких функций листа нет, но возможность есть. И называется она **Макрофункция**. Это аппендикс со старых версий, но работает исправно :)

Для работы макрофункций работа макросов должна быть разрешена. Макофункции нельзя использовать на листе, но можно использовать в создаваемых именах. С помощью этих функций можно определять многое: форматирование ячеек, тип значения, адрес ячейки, номер первой строки с данными, количество страниц, ну и, конечно, вычислять то, что пользователю лень было написать со знаком равно :)

Итак - **ВЫЧИСЛИТЬ**. Функция позволяет вычислять текстовую запись выражения.

Пишем в *D2* нужный текст. Открываем диспетчер имен (*Ctrl+F3*). Жмем *Создать*, пишем имя (например: *считаем*). *Диапазон* - пишем формулу:

```
=ВЫЧИСЛИТЬ(Лист1!$D2)
```

*ОК, Закрыть*. На листе в *E2* пишем формулу:

```
=считаем
```

Важно: если ссылки в имени не закреплены, перед созданием именованной формулы желательно выделить ячейку, в которой будет записана формула, иначе ссылка "поедет" и нужно будет возвращаться для редактирования имени.

Это простенький пример. На практике и формулу имени, и формулу в ячейке можно написать намного сложнее: с условиями, проверками, поиском и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

' ------------------------------------

В *VBA* тоже есть аналог - **Evaluate**. Второй вариант - функция пользователя (UDF):

```
Function EvalText(s As String) As Double
    EvalText = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

Размещается в общем модуле в проекте VBA. В ячейке формула:

```
=EvalText(D2)
```

Comment: Про макрофункцию "Вычислить" не знал. Про функцию на VBA догадывался. Спасибо большое за ликбез!